# wcf service on windows 2003 server - works as server but not as a consumer/client

Tags: wcf

It is a very simple wcf service. Since my original wcf service didn't work there I decided to create one test service. Basically I'm using the default method GetData(int).

I hosted this service on windows 2003 server. It works well when I consume it from a different machine. I use a windows forms test application to consume this service. When I run this forms app on the same ws2003 server and attempt to consume the service on the same server it throws the following error:

There was no endpoint listening at http://...

I created another wcf client using asp.net, also silverlight, nothing works.

Basically, it looks like it can't consume any wcf service.

I couldn't figure out what could be the issue.

Comment: Maybe you need to open a port to consume it from the application or enable WCF in IIS? I have seen issues like those when connecting to an endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the machine had McAfee antivirus installed and was blocking http communication to aspnet_wp.exe.
The full path is c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_wp.exe

Everything works fine after unblocking this specific exe.